# Insert Image Into div after upload

Tags: javascript, php, html, upload, uploadify

Hi guys I use a uploadify script to upload file to FTP and mySQL base. Can u tell me how can I input this uploaded image into image list without site refresh  ?

Below is a div sesiosn which one make image list of added files to article.

```
<div id="image_list">

    <?php foreach($fotos as $foto) { ?>
        <div id="foto_div_<?php echo $foto['id]; ?>" class="foto_div" style="width:410px">
            <div style="float:left; overflow:hidden; margin:0px auto; padding:0px;">
                <img src="<?php echo foto_path($foto['name'].'.'.$foto['extension']); ?>" />
            </div>
            <div style="float:right; width:250px; overflow:hidden; padding-bottom:0px;">
                <input type="hidden" name="foto_<?php echo $foto['id']; ?>" id="foto_<?php echo $foto['id']; ?>" value="1" />
                <h3>Tittle</h3> <br /><input style="width:230px"type="text" name="title_foto_<?php echo $foto['id']; ?>" id="title_foto_<?php echo $foto['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $foto['tittle']; ?>" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <a href="#" onclick="return delete_foto_art(<?php echo $foto['id']; ?>);">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/delete.gif" alt="delete" /> Usuń 
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>        

</div>
```

Uploadify have somthing like OnComplete so i put there a  name of my function  with one should add image to the list;

```
function show_foto(event, queueID, fileObj, response)
    {


        $('#image_list').append(response);

    }
```

In response I get a url to file but image didn't show. Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Put the value returned in `response` here and then we can say why.

Answer (score 1):

you need to append and entire `<img>` element instead of the URL(assuming response returns only the URL).

```
var $img = $("<img>").attr("src", response);
$('#image_list').append($img);
```

Comment: did you inspect your markup after appending the response, is it adding the image? maybe your method `show_foto` is not getting called. try logging and debugging.

Comment: Ok problem was with url but  it add image to div image_list but without foto_div

Comment: Great, then you need to wrap the image with the photo div. like this `$img.wrap("<div class='foto_div'></div>")` and then append it to `$('#image_list')`

Comment: When I fix url first metod also works it's insert picture without div class = 'foto_div'. But tell me mate on this div_class is delete button how site will know with one picute is for delete from datebase ? Meybe i should append array with picture information link name,ext,id(in database) ? How you think